# What type of Exception should I throw when an unknown value is passed into a switch statement

Tags: c#, exception

### Edit 1

Updated to make the enum not an argument to the method...

### Question

This type of problem comes up a lot with enums in switch statements.  In the example code, the developer has accounted for all countries the program is currently using, but if another country is added to the Country enum, an exception should be thrown.   My question is, what type of exception should be thrown?

### Example Code:

```
enum Country
{
    UnitedStates, Mexico,
}

public string GetCallingCode(Guid countryId){
    var country = GetCountry(countryId);
    switch (country)
    {
        case Country.UnitedStates:
            return "1";
            break;
        case Country.Mexico:
            return "52";
            break;
        default:
            // What to throw here
        break;
    }
}
```

I've looked at

- [NotImplemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notimplementedexception.aspx), *The exception that is thrown when a requested method or operation is not implemented.*
- [NotSupported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception.aspx) *There are methods that are not supported in the base class, with the expectation that these methods will be implemented in the derived classes instead. The derived class might implement only a subset of the methods from the base class, and throw NotSupportedException for the unsupported methods.

  For scenarios where it is sometimes possible for the object to perform the requested operation, and the object state determines whether the operation can be performed, see InvalidOperationException.*
- [InvalidOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) *is used in cases when the failure to invoke a method is caused by reasons other than invalid arguments.*

My guess is either NotImplemented or Invalid Operation.  Which one should I use?  Does someone have a better option (I know *rolling* your own is always an option)

Comment: I would throw custom UnknownCountryException. Or at least add  ArgumentOutOfRangeException to your list..

Comment: Only issue I might have with argument exceptions is that they typically are for method arguments. In _this_ particular question's case, it's applicable, but for general switch/case usage, it might not be checking on a method's parameter at all.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Agreed Chris, which is why I updated the sample code...

Comment: @Daryl: I edited my answer. I think there's two separate cases being discussed in the answers. Bottom line I think is that the question/code itself is not exactly a good practice anyway and can be dealt with in other, better ways.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would go with `ArgumentException`, as the agrument is invalid.

EDIT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

There is also `InvalidEnumArgumentException`, which might more accurately describe the problem, however, I have not seen anyone use it before.

Comment: Interestingly, the MSDN seems to use `InvalidEnumArgumentException` exactly for cases like these. But the fact that it inherits from `ArgumentException` and is considered one even by name, makes me question using it for non-argument cases. +1 regardless for finding that little gem and definitely fits perfectly _if_ the enum value is an argument.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to do almost a method contracts check in Debug mode. Throw in an extension method for nice looking form:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static bool AssertIsValid(this System.Enum value)
{
    if (!System.Enum.IsDefined(value.GetType(), value))
        throw new EnumerationValueNotSupportedException(value.GetType(), value); //custom exception
}
```

I figured maybe only have it in debug mode so it passes your development/test environment and unit tests and in production there's no overhead (though that's up to you)

```
public string GetCallingCode(Guid countryId)
{
    var country = GetCountry(countryId);
    country.AssertIsValid(); //throws if the country is not defined
    
    switch (country)
    {
        case Country.UnitedStates:
            return "1";
        case Country.Mexico:
            return "52";
    }
}
```

I would suggest though that this is actually the responsibility of your `GetCountry` method. *It* should recognize that the `countryId` is not valid and throw an exception.

Regardless, this should really be caught by your unit tests too or somehow better handled. Wherever you convert a string/int into your enum should be handled by a singular method which in turn can check/throw (just as any `Parse` method should) and have a unit test that checks all valid numbers.

In general, I don't think the various `ArgumentExceptions` (and the like) are a good candidate because there are several conditions (non-argument) cases. I think if you move the checking code to a single spot, you may as well throw your own exception that accurately communicates to any developer listening.

EDIT: Considering the discussion, I think there are two particular cases here.

### Case 1: Converting underlying type to an equivalent enum

If your methods take some sort of input data (string, int, Guid?), your code performing the conversion into the enum should validate that you have an *actual* enum that's usable. This is the case I posted above in my answer. In such cases, likely throwing your own exception or possibly `InvalidEnumArgumentException`.

This should be treated pretty much like any standard input validation. Somewhere in your system you are providing garbage-in so handle it as you would any other parsing mechanism.

```
var country = GetCountry(countryId);

switch (country)
{
    case Country.UnitedStates:
        return "1";
    case Country.Mexico:
        return "52";
}

private Country GetCountry(Guid countryId)
{
    //get country by ID
    
    if (couldNotFindCountry)
        throw new EnumerationValueNotSupportedException(.... // or InvalidEnumArgumentException

    return parsedCountry;
}
```

EDIT: of course, the compiler requires that your method throws/returns, so not so sure what you should do here. I guess that's up to you. If that actually happens, it probably is a bone-headed exception (case 2 below) since you passed your input validation *yet* did not update the switch/case to handle the new value, so maybe it should `throw new BoneheadedException()`;

### Case 2: Adding a new enumeration value which is not handled by your switch/case blocks in your code

If you are the owner of your code, this falls under the "Boneheaded" exceptions described by Eric Lippert in @NominSim's answer. Though this can actually not result in an exception *at all* while leaving the program in an exceptional/invalid state.

The best for this is likely any place where you perform switch/case (or of the like) runs against the enumeration, you should consider writing a unit test that *automatically* runs the method against *all* defined values of your enumeration. So if you are lazy or accidentally missed a block, your unit tests will warn you that you did not update a method to account for the change in your enumeration listing.

Finally, if your enum is coming from a 3rd party which you did not realize they updated the values, you should write a quick unit test that validates all your expected values. So if you wrote your program with checks for `UnitedStates` and `Mexico`, your unit test should just be a switch/case block for those values and throw an exception otherwise warning you when/if they end up adding `Canada`. When that test fails after updating the 3rd party library, you know what/where you have to make changes to be compatible.

So in this "Case 2", you should throw any old exception you want since it will be handled by your unit tests just so long as it accurately communicates to *you* or consumers of your unit tests just what exactly is missing.

---

In either case, I don't think the switch/case code should be caring too much about invalid input and not throwing exceptions there. They should either be thrown at design time (via unit tests) or thrown when validating/parsing input (and therefore throw appropriate "parsing/validation" exceptions)

---

EDIT: I stumbled upon a [post from Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/24/never-say-never-part-two.aspx) discussing how the C# compiler detects if a method with a return value ever hits its "end point" without returning. The compiler is good at guaranteeing that the end point is unreachable sometimes, but in cases as yours above, *we developers* know it's unreachable (except in the circumstances noted above where `BoneheadedExceptions` come into play).

What wasn't discussed (at least that I saw) what you should do as a developer to resolve these cases. The compiler *requires* that you provide a return value or throw an exception even if you *know* it will never reach that code. Googling hasn't magically surfaced some exception to leverage in this case (though I couldn't figure out good search terms), and I'd rather throw an exception and be informed that my *assumption* that it cannot reach the end is incorrect rather than returning *some value* which may not inform me of the problem or result in unwanted behaviour. Maybe some `UnexpectedCodePathFailedToReturnValueException` of some sort would be most valid in this case. When I have some time, I'll do some more digging and maybe post a question on [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) to garner some discussion.

Comment: hmm... maybe I'll create a, HeyYouDummyDeveloperYouTotallForgotToUpdateThisSwitchStatmentException?  :) What do think?  Even though I'm joking about the name, that is the true purpose for which I'm throwing an exception.

Comment: @Daryl Yeah, you could have something like `CodeShouldNotHaveGotHereException` :) Probably more of a question of professionalism then if you would want your clients to be seeing logs with such messages.

Comment: @Daryl I added another interesting thought on the concept at the end of my answer. Eric Lippert has a good read on the concept of the compiler detecting code paths and end points of methods that return values and I think it's pretty applicable the case here.

Answer (score 2):

Of the exceptions you've listed, only `InvalidOperationException` fits your scenario.  I would consider using either this, or either [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) or the more specific [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx) since your `switch` value is provided as an argument.

Or, as you say, roll your own.

**EDIT:** Based on your updated question, I would suggest `InvalidOperationException` if you want to use a framework exception.  However, for this more generic case, I would definitely prefer to roll my own - you can't guarantee that `InvalidOperationException` won't be caught elsewhere in the callstack (possibly by the framework itself!), so using your own exception type is much more robust.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) if the value you're working with is a product purely of your object's current state. As it says:

> The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state.

Even with your updated question, since the particular value you cannot deal properly with was derived from an argument passed to it, I would still use an `ArgumentException` - you can explain in the error message that information you're *derived* from the argument doesn't match anything you can deal with.

---

For both `NotImplementedException` and `NotSupportedException` the expectation is that, no matter what the caller does, they're not going to be able to remedy the situation. Whereas `ArgumentException` and `InvalidOperationException` are clues that, if the caller would use a different argument, or transition the object to another state (respectively), the call might work.

Comment: I like the thought that NotImplemented conveys that it isn't every going to work... good point.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I don't think this is the proper place for any Exception at all. If you add a Country, you should add a case to the switch statement. The code shouldn't break because you add a value to an enum.

There is an [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) on when to use exceptions by Eric Lippert, that categorizes the type of exception you are looking for as: (forgive the wording it is not mine)

> **Boneheaded** exceptions are your own darn fault, *you could have prevented them and therefore they are bugs in your code*. **You should not catch them; doing so is hiding a bug in your code.** Rather, you should *write your code so that the exception cannot possibly happen in the first place*, and therefore does not need to be caught.

Comment: Agreed that you should add the case, but if someone else adds the enum value 5 years later, do you think they're going to know to add a case?

Comment: Love Eric Lippert, and agree with what he's saying, but if for example, this program was used to auto-dial a country and you don't include the exception, what do you do? Return 0? -1?  Odds are that will throw an even worse exception later down the line, or you end up calling Kenya when you wanted China...

Comment: @Daryl Honestly if I were writing this code I would probably encapsulate the country code (and any other information) within a separate struct or object so that adding a Country involves adding other necessary elements like the country code. That way further down the line, if someone wants to add a country, they are required to add the country code as well. If you throw an exception like you say, then the same issue occurs (a person can add a country without adding a case) but the program will just crash on them (which is *not* good) Better to put the "adding" all in one location IMO.

Comment: Totally agree.  But what if the enum is owned by a third party dll???  Rather than focusing on creating the best possible solution with some assumptions, lets focus on the question as is.  +1  :)

Comment: You are referring to this quote out of context.  You are right that **the exception should not be caught**, but the question is **what exception should be thrown?**  And one definitely *should* be thrown, else you cannot be sure to recognise the places you have missed updating!

Comment: @NominSim: as Daryl said, your comment is assuming that the author of the country code is the only person consuming it.  This is a huge assumption to make; we all make frequent use of enums that are outside out control and may well be modified in the future to include values we couldn't predict.

Comment: @DanPuzey Throwing this type of exception is covered in the same article: "Vexing exceptions are the *result of unfortunate design decisions*. Vexing exceptions are thrown in a completely non-exceptional circumstance, and therefore must be caught and handled all the time... **"Try to never write a library yourself that throws a vexing exception**" In either case the argument from the article applies, the code should be written in a way that does not cause exceptions that do not represent exceptional circumstances.

Comment: @Daryl Regardless I still don't think throwing an exception is the proper action in this case. If you don't own the enum, you should have test code run against it to make sure you're accounting for every case. Read my last comment to DanPuzey esp. "Try to never write a library yourself that throws a vexing exception".

Comment: @NominSim: The way to avoid throwing vexing exceptions here would be to use the try-er/do-er pattern, so that calling code that is prepared to deal with an invalid country can do so without the overhead of processing an exception; that would still leave the question, though, of what exception should be thrown by the "do-er" (if the caller isn't going to be prepared to handle an invalid country code, it's better to have an exception thrown from the code which recognizes the condition, than to have it return something bogus to the caller).

Comment: @supercat You're still throwing the vexing exception though, you shouldn't be using exceptions to perform program logic.

Comment: I would not count this as a vexing exception.  I would count this as a very necessary exception in the situation that an enum value has not been handled in code that is expected to handle it.

Comment: @NominSim: Given that an external DLL *could* add a value to the enum that your code might not be updated to handle - given that your tests can equally not include a value that they are not aware of - and given that it's an inordinate amount of effort to review all code for every reference to every enum that might ever be touched just because you've taken an updated library - what would your preferred solution be?

Comment: @NominSim: If the caller is prepared to deal with the condition, then the caller should use a `TryGetCallingCode` method, which would do something other than throw an exception if a country code was invalid.  The only way an exception would get thrown would be if the caller isn't prepared to deal with it, in which case an exception *should* be thrown.

Comment: @DanPuzey There are numerous other solutions possible that do not throw exceptions. The fact that an enum value should be expected to be handled by the OPs code *makes it a vexing exception*. Exceptions should occur *only* during *exceptional* circumstances.

Comment: I think we'd have to agree to disagree here.  This to my mind is an exception that *should* be thrown but should *never* be caught: it is an artifact of defensive coding style that a consumer of the method should never need to be aware of except when some other process (of development) has failed.  Any of the alternative solutions (returning failure, for example) would be more unwieldy to consume.

Comment: @DanPuzey I see your reasoning, I just feel like giving the default case an exception can lead to undesired affects later down the line.  It essentially "breaks" the code if someone were to add a Country later down the line. I am kind of grumbling at the fact that this received 2 down votes, the idea that throwing an Exception is better than handling the issue yourself shouldn't be promoted.

Comment: No one is promoting that "throwing an Exception is better than handling the issue yourself". Reread the definition of Boneheaded exceptions that you quoted. If someone adds an enum value but doesn't handle it, it is appropriate to throw a Boneheaded exception to indicate "there's a bug here, come fix it".

Comment: @default.kramer Someone should be able to add an enum value without the OPs code crashing the program. Which is why an exception should not be used in this case.The OP wants to account for if someone adds an enum value, but the way to account for it isn't to say "Ok now the program is broken".

Answer (score -1):

Since .NET 7 you can use the [UnreachableException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.unreachableexception) class. As per documentation the exception is designed for cases *when the program executes an instruction that was thought to be unreachable*. Nowadays it's widely used for exactly such cases by the .NET runtime itself ([example](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/825f053e069f1cbb7bc8616693b65e3a98466ec3/src/libraries/System.Runtime.InteropServices/gen/Microsoft.Interop.SourceGeneration/DiagnosticOr.cs#L83)).

```cs
public enum Country
{
    UnitedStates, Mexico,
}

public static string GetCallingCode(Country country)
{
    return country switch 
    { 
        Country.UnitedStates => "1", 
        Country.Mexico => "52", 
        _ => throw new UnreachableException() 
    };
}
```

Answer (score -2):

it's impossible to pass another value, because your enum limits the possible values to the one you handle. so you don't need any exception.

Comment: I think the issue would be if they add a new enum value, this would handle that case rather than going through an empty default and continuing in a bad state.

Comment: Not true.  Enums derive from numeric types; you can call `GetCallingCode((Country)42)` without error.  Also, the enum might be extended later and the new values not supported; this is a common way of future-proofing your code.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair that was more or less my thinking.